# Cuantas veces se puede utilizar window.addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Estoy empezando mi proyecto pero quisiera saber cuantas veces se puede utilizar esta función para cargar varias funciones

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
alert("Hola");
});
```

sin que me vaya a dar fallas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La idea es que no utilices `window.addEventListener("load", function()` por cada funcion que quieras ejecutar.

Puedes ejecutas las funciones que necesites dentro de un mismo `window.addEventListener("load", function()`

**Ejemplo:**

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    hello();
    bye();
});


function hello(){
  alert("hello");
}


function bye(){
  alert("bye");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Este fragmento solo se llama una vez y es cuando todos los recursos externos y la estructura del dom están listos.

No debe afectar en el rendimiento de la forma en que está.

Pudiera ser el equivalente de

```
 document.ready
```

De JQuery

Sin embargo debes considerar que es lo que deseas hacer realmente dado que dispones de:

- Load que espera al dom y los recursos externos
- DOMContentLoaded el cual solo espera al dom

En cualquiera de los casos si tú función o funciones no dependen de archivos externos deberían funcionar, pues este llamado que pones solo se hace una vez asignandolo al objeto window

Comment: Hola @Aprendiz. Considere cambiar `document.ready` por `$(document).ready()`, ya que la primera devolverá `undefined` en la consola.

Comment: @David solo era una referencia para dar un poco de contexto de dónde podía ver una equivalencia ya que ciertamente no me manejo en JQuery